# Rails 4: Rake scraper task not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Building a rental scraper using 3 taps API. And want to delete some old posts.

After creating a new anchor in the rails console

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > @anchor = Anchor.new
 => #<Anchor id: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > @anchor.value ="1795931327"
 => "1795931327" 
2.0.0p247 :003 > 
2.0.0p247 :004 > Anchor.first.value
  Anchor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "anchors".* FROM "anchors"   ORDER BY "anchors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "1795931327"
```

I now want to delete the old posts i have in my database (currently I have 1000 posts) which have not been updated for over 2 days.

so i want to show new listings so I type

```
Neils-MacBook-Pro-2:craigslist_scraper1 neilpatel$ rake scraper: destroy_all_posts
```

but i get error

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'scraper:'

I know this has worked in the past because in my scraper.rake file i have this

```
desc "Destroy all posting data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end
```

any ideas??

changed to

namespace :scraper do
  desc "Destroy all posting data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end 
end

post_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: In `rake scraper: destroy_all_posts` - is there a space between `scraper:` and `destroy_all_posts`? try `rake scraper:destroy_all_posts`

Comment: tried without the space , got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `namespace` in your `scraper.rake` file. This should work:

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Destroy all posting data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end 
end
```

If you then type `rake -T scraper`, you should see:

```
rake scraper:destroy_all_posts  # Destroy all posting data
```

Comment: Made the changes , ran rake -T scraper and  got ->  rake scraper:scrape  # Fetch Craigslist posts from 3Tap

Answer (score 0):

```
desc "Destroy all posting data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end
```

this task was running outside the loop , not inside , retested now working